# How to count the files and directories by excluding dot folders in command prompt?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am using `dir /s` to view all the files and directives in my folder. But this also displaying . directories. I am almost having more than 100 top level and inside folders. When I execute above command the result is not accurate.

How to get the exact files and directories count using window command prompt?

Comment: So just because **YOU** want some directories **not** counted the result is not accurate? You will have to set up a batch/script to count the way you want. There are examples for that here [SU] or on [SO].

Answer (score 1):

Count files recursively:

```
set filesCount=0 & (for /R %f in (*) do @(set /a filesCount+=1 > nul)) & set filescount
```

Count directories recursively:

```
set dirsCount=0 & (for /D /R %f in (*) do @(set /a dirsCount+=1 > nul)) & set dirscount
```

Resource: [`FOR` loop commands](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html).

**Edit**: if you care about hidden files, compare the following results:

```
d:\bat> set filesCount=0 & (for /R %f in (*) do @(set /a filesCount+=1 > nul)) & set filescount
filesCount=3095

d:\bat> set filesCount=0 & (for /F "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /s /a-h-d') do @(set /a filesCount+=1 > nul)) & set filescount
filesCount=3095

d:\bat> set filesCount=0 & (for /F "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /s /ah-d') do @(set /a filesCount+=1 > nul)) & set filescount
filesCount=10

d:\bat> set filesCount=0 & (for /F "delims=" %f in ('dir /b /s /a-d') do @(set /a filesCount+=1 > nul)) & set filescount
filesCount=3105
```

Apply to directories ([mutatis mutandis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutatis_mutandis)) using `dir` switches `/aD`, `/aHD` and `/a-HD` sequentially.

Comment: This will exclude hidden files and directories also?

Comment: @Mihir answer updated.